# Problem in rearranging rows and columns of an array

Tags: c++

In general, given the task:

A permissible matrix transformation is a permutation of two adjacent rows or two neighboring columns. A real square matrix of order n (n <= 12) is given. Using valid converters, you can get a matrix in which the maximum element is in the upper left corner. Elements were used to perform valid conversions.

My problem is precisely that I cannot swap adjacent rows or columns.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const int rows = 4, cols = rows;
int iMax = 0;
int jMax = 0;

int arr[rows][cols];

void arr_f()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << " " << arr[i][j] << "\t";

            if (arr[i][j] > arr[iMax][jMax])
            {
                iMax = i;
                jMax = j;

            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "The maximum number of array: " << arr[iMax][jMax] << endl << endl;

}


    int main()
    {
        arr_f();
        system("pause");
    }
```

Tried to add features

```
inline void swap_columns(const int f, const int s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        swap(arr[i][f], arr[i][s]);
    }
}
inline void swap_rows(const int f, const int s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        swap(arr[f][i], arr[s][i]);
    }
}
```

and add the following to the arr_f () function:

```
swap_rows(0, iMax);
    swap_columns(0, jMax);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << " " << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

But in this case, the rows (and columns) do not change as expected (the row in which the maximum value is located is immediately replaced by the first row, ignoring the rest).

Comment: Do you mean that it should swap rows and columns one by one until it reaches the top left? As is you only tell it to swap iMax and jMax with index 0 so you should only see one set of swaps. Let me know if swapping one at a time is what you intend and I can help from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obtained a wrong result, because `swap_columns` and `swap_rows` make operations that are not allowed. You need to make them this way:

```
inline void swap_columns(const int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        swap(arr[i][k], arr[i][k+1]);
    }
}
inline void swap_rows(const int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        swap(arr[k][i], arr[k+1][i]);
    }
}
```

And apply this way:

```
    for (int k = iMax-1; k >= 0; --k)
      swap_rows(k);
    for (int k = jMax-1; k >= 0; --k)
      swap_columns(k);
```

Certainly, this may be improved by moving larger blocks, but this is a matter of optimization.

Comment: I recommend expanding on *You obtained a wrong result, because swap_columns and swap_rows make operations that are not allowed.* so that it provides more information.

Comment: "A permissible matrix transformation is a permutation of two adjacent rows or two neighboring columns" — the initial version swapped non-adjacent rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

To swap adjacent rows and columns, just replace this:

```
    swap_rows(0, iMax);
    swap_columns(0, jMax);
```

with this:

```
    swap_rows(iMax + 1, iMax);
    swap_columns(jMax + 1, jMax);
```

However, it is not clear from the problem description, whether this would always be the desired solution. And if iMax happens to be the last row index, then iMax + 1 would be out of bounds and fail at run time. In that case, perhaps iMax - 1 would be required instead.